# Is a link_to a custom route or a form the best way to provide state change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the 'Rails way' to provide access to methods such as the following from a view

```
def approve!
  self.update_attribute status, 'approved'
end
```

Is it best to create a link to a custom route

```
<%= link_to 'Approve', approve_object_path(@object) %>

#objects_controller.rb
def approve
  @object.approve!
end
```

Or to create an update form

```
<%= simple_form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :status, input_html { value: 'approved' }, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

On the one hand, using a form and not using the `approve!` method at all seems to align better with restful routes.

On the other hand, a link to a custom route seems to provide less opportunity for submitted values to be manipulated by the user, and also requires less code to implement.

Which is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Since it's changing state of the object, make it a `patch` or `post` route and mention the method in `link_to`. I prefer the `link_to` approach.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed coming back to this issue after some time. Do you know whether using `link_to` has any impact on SEO and search engine crawlers? e.g., could actions be triggered when the site is crawled (ignoring user auth for now)?

Comment: `link_to` is a view helper and it gives you traditional `<a>` tag when rendered. So no complications on SEO or anything else.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed yes, but `<a>` tags are not expected to enact inpage changes or modify the underlying data. Wouldn't crawlers expect to see a button for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a preferred best practice, per se...

Just my opinion, but I normally do the `link_to` approach, and for an "state machine" like your example.  The need for an entire form for a simple action like this is a lot of extra code that isn't necessary when an action can be called to change the state.

The counter argument to this is that it breaks CRUD, and requires a non-CRUD route.  Convention over configuration champions would probably prefer an entire new controller to change the state of the object.

TL;DR - I do the `link_to` approach, and I use `:remote => true` to make it asynchronous so the page doesn't even reload (unless you need the page to redirect elsewhere).

Comment: coming back to this issue after some time. Do you know whether using `link_to` has any impact on SEO and search engine crawlers? e.g., could actions be triggered when the site is crawled (ignoring user auth for now)?

Answer (score 1):

You can change state remotely with both the scenarios.
But I think if only a state has to be changed then use `link_to`. As we don't need to have form features with listed attributes in `params` here.

Comment: coming back to this issue after some time. Do you know whether using `link_to` has any impact on SEO and search engine crawlers? e.g., could actions be triggered when the site is crawled (ignoring user auth for now)?